# Viewing an Android application database

Tags: android, database

Is there a way to view an application database on an Android device? The only solution I've found requires a developer device and I don't have one. I know I can root it and get the same result, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way other than rooting the device.

Comment: Why? It's a security thing. You wouldn't want apps randomly messing with other apps' databases, right? If it's YOUR application, you can write some java code to dump the database to the sdcard or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view/edit what is in the database you can follow the instructions near the end of this blog post:

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

I used this method to make sure data was being written correctly and to add data as well.
For more on ADB: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Hope this helps

[Edit] I just re-read your question and I realize you may have been asking to view the database from your Android device - **the method I suggested in the link allows you to view/edit from a computer with the ADB** - NOT on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your .db on the SD Card, you can view it without root privileges. But, this is probably not what you want to do for your production app. Otherwise you need a dev phone or one with root access.

If you want a visual tool to open/display your .db files, MOTODEV Studio allows you to open an arbitrary .db file from your SD card. Look in the "MOTODEV Database" perspective for the ability to map a file to a database.  developer.motorola.com