# External Database access in Android

Tags: android, database

Can I talk to the database of another application from inside my code?

Comment: Can you provide more details, If another application has content provider to access its data, then you probably can do.

Answer (score 0):

Only, If that **database is not a private to that application**. (Also if your device is rooted then you can access any application's database) Also if that database is like a content Provider then you can access other application's database in your application. Like Android native phonebook database. (As it used their database as a content Provider.)

Comment: Hello, SQLite database is private to application which created it, so there might not be a question of public database.

Comment: @iNan - If you write a database file in with MODE_WORLD_READABLE permission then its possible. As by default its private to your application.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not.

[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335136/android-accessing-information-from-sqlitedatabase-in-other-classes)

But you can try it by rooting the phone

link >> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742035/viewing-an-android-application-database)

Reading DB from SDCARD>>

see the location of DB file then create a method inside a class, the method is like:

```
public class DB_Path {
public final SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
        File dbfile = new File("path of file like : /sdcard/TheDataBaseFile");
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
             return db;
    }
```

### }

initialize like

```
  public DB_Path dbp = new DB_Path();
  public SQLiteDatabase db = dbp.getDB();
```

after that you can call the cursor with db.

```
 Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("the sql query",null);
```

Reference link >> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481983/create-database-from-prestored-db-file-on-sdcard)

How to get table names from database >> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681744/android-get-list-of-tables)

Comment: produces the "sqlite3_open_v2("...', &handle, 6, NULL) error!